# Rails Tutorial Chapter 9, 9.2.2 - 43 Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Got to end of this section in the Rails tutorial and all my tests failing. Any help would be much appreciated.

My Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
      before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @user = User.new
      end

      def edit
      end

      def update
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
          redirect_to @user
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
          sign_in @user
          flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
          redirect_to @user
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      private

        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                       :password_confirmation)
        end

        # Before filters

        def signed_in_user
          redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
        end

        def correct_user
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
          redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
        end
    end
```

My authentication spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before {sign_in user}

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { patch user_path(user) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
        before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My session helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                                  User.hash(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end
end
```

Just been asked about the User.rb model file, so here it is....

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token

  has_secure_password
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.hash(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.hash(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

Comment: What is your errors saying??

Comment: Could you give a couple of examples of the tests failing so we can see the error please.

Comment: 30) User pages signup with valid information after saving the user
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { visit signup_path }←[0m
     ←[31mActionView::Template::Error←[0m:
       ←[31mundefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x558c438>←[0m

Comment: thats one of the errors (1 of the 43)

Comment: More examples........←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:48←[0m ←[36m# Static pages shoul d have the right links on the layout←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8←[0m ←[36m# Static pages About page it should behave like all static pages ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:9←[0m ←[36m# Static pages About page it should behave like all static pages ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:18←[0m ←[36m# Static pages Home page ←[0m

Comment: seems like the common theme with the errors is this line: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x5533290>

Comment: Have you defined the `digest` method in `User` model class?

Comment: @KirtiThorat - added file into the post

Comment: @Justin errors in comments

Comment: @GraemeMcLean - errors in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `digest` class method on `User` model BUT have not defined it yet which is why you get the error as `undefined method 'digest'`

In your `User` model, add the following method:

```
  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end
```

Refer to [8.2 Signin success](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_success) section for the details.

Comment: Thanks Kirti. I have User.hash(token) method in the User model, not User.digest(token). Changing it does not fix it though

Comment: You would definitely be getting less errors now. You can update your question with the error messages and relevant specs. I can take a look at it then.

Comment: Hi Kirti - I have fixed it. Somewhere along the lines the User.hash() method got updated to User.digest() and I had to replace all references to the old method. I now get all test to pass. Thanks for your help.